# fire base cloud function is not working in node.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am running this code when I run node index.js command in CMD it works perfectly but same code is not running when I am using it into firebase cloud function. I might be wrong but not able to find the issue I am searching this issue for 1 week.
this code is working

```
stripe.customers.create({
    email: 'testemail@gmail.com',
  }).then((customer) => {
    return null;
    // functions.firestore.document('data/{card}/payment/{tokenid}').set(customer.id)
  });
```

but this is not working

```
exports.StripeSource =functions.firestore.document('data/{card}/tokens/{tokenid}').onCreate((user) => {
  return stripe.customers.create({
    email: 'testemail@gmail.com',
  }).then((customer) => {
    return null;
    // functions.firestore.document('data/{card}/payment/{tokenid}').set(customer.id)
  });
});
```

fire base functions log is

```
 {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":
{"code":3,"message":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"},"authenticationInfo":
{"principalEmail":"name.dev@domain.tv"},"requestMetadata":{"requestAttributes":
{},"destinationAttributes":
{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.fun
ctions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/payment
bystripe/locations/us-central1/functions/StripeSource"}
```

visual studio code terminal report here

```
C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_stripe_payment1\android\functions\functions>firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'paymentbystripe'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_stripe_payment1\android\functions\functions
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (37.28 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function StripeSource(us-central1)...
!  functions[StripeSource(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        StripeSource


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:StripeSource


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_stripe_payment1\android\functions\functions>
```

Comment: did you follow the cloud function documentation ?

Comment: yes I follow but error not resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not install stripe. I recommend you to look your dependencies in `package.json` and add `"stripe":"^6.20.0"`. Any new version of this will do the trick.

Finally run Firebase deploy. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank it perfectly works. I did run npm install stripe --save but package did not add now I add manually and it working now. thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

This error means the deployment script could not find the stripe package. You probably have the stripe module installed globally but it is not referenced explicitly in your package.json for this project.

When you deploy firebase function the deployment script takes your package.json and pulls all of the dependencies. It will not look for dependencies installed locally on your machine.

Either add the stripe dependency manually to the package.json or run:

```
npm install stripe
```

then verify the stripe module has been added to your package.json file.

Comment: yes I did run npm install stripe but did not works I did manually add it thanks